# Getting value error of "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.." while checking for equality between sub-strings in a string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, valueerror

I'm trying to check if a specific "Route" string starts and ends with the same sub-string but I'm getting an error of 
"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
if df1["Route"].str[:3] == df1["Route"].str[-3:]:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

I've tried resolving the issue by use of suggested methods mentioned for similar queries in SO but to no avail..

Here's the snippet from the column "Route" that I'm trying to apply this query on:
BBIBOMAMD
STVBLRTRV
AMDDELAMD
AMDCCUAMD
AMDBOMAMD
PNQAMDPNQ
DELAMDDEL
AMDGOAAMD

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide data set sample to reproduce the error. Please check the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a pandas series as the predicate for the `if` condition and that is not a valid operation.

Let me show what I mean by that.

```
df1["Route"].str[:3]
```

gives

```
0    BBI
1    STV
2    AMD
3    AMD
4    AMD
5    PNQ
6    DEL
7    AMD
Name: Route, dtype: object
```

```
df1["Route"].str[-3:]
```

which gives:

```
0    AMD
1    TRV
2    AMD
3    AMD
4    AMD
5    PNQ
6    DEL
7    AMD
Name: Route, dtype: object
```

So now when you use these two as part of the `if` condition python complains that the True value is ambiguous.

I am assuming that you want to print True or False for each row in the 'Route' column.
What you can try is the following.

```
df1['Route'].apply(lambda x: x[:3] == x[-3:])
```

which will print the following.

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: Route, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks @abhilb, it does solve the purpose. Can I still compare the resultant for the next set of operations? i.e. `if (df1['Route'].apply(lambda y: y[:3] == y[-3:]) is True: then <something> else: <something else>` ?

Comment: It gives a series of Boolean values. so you can say if all of them are True or if any one of them is True etc.